# regex to convert string to json array

Tags: java, regex

I am getting raw json array without quotes when I execute rest template. How can convert it to valid json array? I have tried with following regex,

```
str.replace("([a-zA-Z0-9-]+):([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)g", "\"$1\":\"$2\"")
```

Its not working as expected. Here is my json array,

```
{
    items = [
        {
            VALUE1 = 1,
            VALUE2 = v1,
            VALUE3 = high temp,
            VALUE4 = null
        }, {
            VALUE1 = 1,
            VALUE2 = v1,
            VALUE3 = low temp,
            VALUE4 = null
        }, {
            VALUE1 = 1,
            VALUE2 = v1.1,
            VALUE3 = Not valid,
            VALUE4 = null
        }
    ]
}
```

How to convert this as valid json array, so that i can parse it properly. Thank you.

Comment: Start by removing the `g` at the end, and ask yourself why you included a `:` in the middle when the data uses `=`.

Comment: Use `"([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) = ([ .a-zA-Z0-9-]+)"`. See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pbTN0c/1)

Comment: @Andreas this doesn't fix the `items` key though

Comment: Is that really your json data or is it how it is printed to the console?

Comment: @SteffenJacobs Of course not. You need to different regex for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful: You do not want to put double quote characters around numeric quantities such as `1` or special values such as `null`.  The following program does the replacement in two parts. First it looks for dictionary keys and puts quotes around them:

```
String json = s.replaceAll("\\b(\\w+)\\s*=\\s*", "\"$1\": ");
```

This looks for word characters beginning on a word boundary folowed by 0 or more spaces followed by `=` followed by 0 or more spaces and quotes the word following it by a `:` and a single space.

The second part looks for string dictionary values using both a positive *lookbehind assertion* and negative *lookahead assertion*:

```
json = json.replaceAll("(?<=\": )(?!\\[|\\{|(?:(?:null|\\d+)[,}\n]))([^,}\n]*)", "\"$1\"");
```

The value must be preceded by `":` (positive lookbehind assertion) but must not be any of `[`, `{`, `null` or a number (negative lookahead assertion). Then we take everything up to but not including the next comma, right brace or newline character as the value to be quoted.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s =  "{\n" +
                    "items = [{\n" +
                    "VALUE1 = 1,\n" +
                    "VALUE2 = v1,\n" +
                    "VALUE3 = high temp,\n" +
                    "VALUE4 = null\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "}, {\n" +
                    "VALUE1 = 1,\n" +
                    "VALUE2 = v1,\n" +
                    "VALUE3 = low temp,\n" +
                    "VALUE4 = null\n" +
                    "}, {\n" +
                    "VALUE1 = 1,\n" +
                    "VALUE2 = v1.1,\n" +
                    "VALUE3 = Not valid,\n" +
                    "VALUE4 = null\n" +
                    "}]";
[A-F0-9]{2}(:[A-F0-9]{2})*:?");
        String json = s.replaceAll("\\b(\\w+)\\s*=\\s*", "\"$1\": ");
        json = json.replaceAll("(?<=\": )(?!\\[|\\{|(?:(?:null|\\d+)[,}\n]))([^,}\n]*)", "\"$1\"");
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
{
"items": [{
"VALUE1": 1,
"VALUE2": "v1",
"VALUE3": "high temp",
"VALUE4": null

}, {
"VALUE1": 1,
"VALUE2": "v1",
"VALUE3": "low temp",
"VALUE4": null
}, {
"VALUE1": 1,
"VALUE2": "v1.1",
"VALUE3": "Not valid",
"VALUE4": null
}]
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
str.replace("\b(?!null)([a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+[^ =,]?|[0-9]+)", "\"$1\"").replace("=",":")
```

Its supposed to work in your specific case as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/jRPqnF/7)

Comment: Look what the regex did to the value with key, `VALUE4`. And besides, `null` is a special value that should probably not be quoted (likewise values that are numbers).

Comment: You're right. I'll correct it

Comment: Fixed the problem